# Spark command not supported in Unity Catalog in databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I have my Unity Catalog enabled and running in my workspace and I am looking to create a view on one of the column "requestProjectUrlName" . I am able to create a view by one project name by running the below command . Here for ex, i am able to create view where my column has data "XYZ" in it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW main.deltalake_db.Customers_Log_Table_RLS AS
 SELECT *
 FROM main.deltalake_db.Customers_Log_Table
 WHERE
   CASE
     WHEN requestProjectUrlName = "XYZ"
     ELSE FALSE
   END;
```

However when i try to create multiple views with project names by running a loop as below

```
distinctprojects = df.select('requestProjectUrlName').distinct()
target_database = "main.deltalake_db"
for project in distinctprojects.collect():
    project_name = project['requestProjectUrlName']
    view_name = f"view_{project_name.replace(' ', '_').replace('-', '_')}"
    create_view_query = f"""
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `{target_database}`.`{view_name}` AS
    SELECT * FROM main.deltalake_db.Customers_Log_Table
    WHERE requestProjectUrlName = '{project_name}'
    """
    spark.sql(create_view_query)
```

Here my df is nothing but the dataframe and distinctprojects does give me all unique project names.

I receive error as `[UC_COMMAND_NOT_SUPPORTED] Creating a persistent view that references both Unity Catalog and Hive Metastore objects is not supported in Unity Catalog.`  What wrong am i doing here?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that in your PySpark code you're using the following statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `{target_database}`.`{view_name}`
```

If you compare it with your original SQL query you will see that you use 2-level name: `database.view`, while original query used the 3-level name: `catalog.database.view`.

By default, if you don't specify the catalog it's defaulting to the `hive_metastore`, and that's why you get the error.

You have few options to fix it:

- add catalog name explicitly:

```
target_catalog = 'main'
...

create_view_query = f"""
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `{target_catalog}`.`{target_database}`.`{view_name}`
...
"""
```

- set default catalog via Spark conf properties as described in [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/unity-catalog/hive-metastore.html#default-catalog) (although it's not really recommended).